# Unable to fetch the NFT of the contract I deployed

Tags: tokens, nft, polygon, moralis

I deployed an ERC721 smart contract on Polygon.

The contract address is as follows: 0x9Bc7eBE1a407eb2A7E7C6CECf14e964a7fd79cE6

Moralis, however, does not give me anything back when I fetch the tokens contained within.
Example:

```
const options = {
  chain: 'matic',
  addresses: '0x9Bc7eBE1a407eb2A7E7C6CECf14e964a7fd79cE6', 
};

Moralis.Web3API.token.getTokenMetadata(options)
```

Response:

```
[
  {
    address: '0x9bc7ebe1a407eb2a7e7c6cecf14e964a7fd79ce6',
    name: '',
    symbol: '',
    decimals: ''
  }
]
```

Despite this OpenSea display the nft.
I tried them all but nothing ..
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `getNFTMetadata` when trying to obtain metadata of an ERC-721 contract. `getTokenMetadata` is for an ERC-20.

Comment: When i use: getNFTMetadata() I get the right answer, namely:
`{
  token_address: '0x9bc7ebe1a407eb2a7e7c6cecf14e964a7fd79ce6',
  name: 'myTest',
  symbol: 'MTST',
  contract_type: 'ERC721',
  synced_at: '2022-02-03'
}` 
but how can i retrive the metadata of a single nft?